# How to use divs & spans in HTML5

Tags: html, css-tables

HTML markup is used to represent structure, while CSS is used to define presentation.

To my understanding, elements are supposed to give semantic meaning to what a section of a web page represents. `<div>` were used in HTML4 with semantic meaning artificially added via `id` & `class`. That is why in HTML5 new block elements such as `<nav>`, `<main>`,  `<header>`, `<footer>` etc. - whose semantic meanings are built-in & implicit - are introduced for common uses. This leads me to two questions.

I know that `<div>` can still be used for sections of a web page whose semantic meaning aren't represented by the newly introduced elements. `<span>` continues to be used without change as no new inline elements are introduced (afaik) to substitute them as had happened to `<div>`.

One other use in particular are CSS tables. Considering that HTML elements are supposed to convey semantic meanings, and that the `display` property modifies the layout of elements, is there a difference between using `<div>` or `<span>` to represent tables? If yes, how do I decide which to use?

Besides the aforementioned, are there any other uses for these two elements in HTML5 as a best practice, in the same sense that it is best practice not to use `<table>` for non-tabular data?

Answer (score 3):

> Considering that HTML elements are supposed to convey semantic meanings, and that the display property modifies the layout of elements, is there a difference between using `<div>` or `<span>` to represent tables?

The difference is the rendering when the CSS isn't applied (because it failed to load, or a speech browser is involved, or the user is using lynx, or whatever).

If you have tabular data. Use a table. Otherwise use whatever element makes the most sense.

> Besides the aforementioned, are there any other uses for these two elements in HTML5 as a best practice, in the same sense that it is best practice not to use `<table>` for non-tabular data?

The rule of thumb for best practise element selection is unchanged by the introduction of HTML 5: Pick the element that has the semantics that best describes the data. If no element has semantics that correctly describe the data, then use div or span since they don't have any semantics associated with them (and no semantic information is better than wrong semantic information).